# Finding a function where the area under the curve in the first 80% of an interval is equal to the last 20% of an interval.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to create an experience equation for a game I am working on. I have come up with this equality but don't know where to go from here to solve it.

$$ \int_0^{0.8a}f(x)dx=\int_{0.8a}^{a}f(x)dx $$

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I would consider the function $f(x)=ce^{tx}$ and for example $a=5$ and then play around with $c$ and $t$, if you want approximate solution, or computing them analytically for the exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that satisfies your constraint independent of $a$ is a power function.

Consider the ansatz $y=x^p,p>-1$ having equal area between $[0,\epsilon a]$ and $[\epsilon a,a],\epsilon\in (0,1).$ Your setup has $\epsilon=0.8$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
&\int _0^{\epsilon a}x^pdx=\int _{\epsilon a}^a x^pdx\\
&\implies \frac{(\epsilon a)^{p+1}}{p+1}=\frac{( a)^{p+1}}{p+1}-\frac{(\epsilon a)^{p+1}}{p+1}\\
&\implies 2\epsilon ^{p+1}=1\\
&\implies p=-1-\frac{\ln 2}{\ln \epsilon }\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: wow, that makes so much sense! thanks so much

Comment: @abcdjoe no prob

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be $f(x)=e^{kx}$. So
$$\int_0^{\frac  45a}f(x)\,dx=\int_{\frac  45a}^{a}f(x)\,dx \implies e^{ak}-2e^{\frac  45ak}+1=0$$ Let $e^{ak}=z^5$ and you need to solve for $z$ the quintic
$$z^5-2 z^4+1=(z-1) \left(z^4-z^3-z^2-z-1\right)=0$$ The quartic can be solved with radicals and the acceptable real solution is
$$z= 1.9275619754829253043\cdots \implies a k=3.2812798961848790424\cdots$$

If you want to claim for a "nice" result
$$z\sim \frac{751 e^2+343 e-955}{133 e^2+666 e+74}\implies ak\sim 5 \log \left(\frac{751 e^2+343 e-955}{133 e^2+666 e+74}\right)$$ which, for $z$, is in a relative error of $9.89\times 10^{-18}$%.